# Use of conv_integer in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I am in the process of trying to write some code that will simply just shift a 32 bit vector left or right, with a 5 bit input that will be used for the shift amount (`shamt`).  The issue I am having is trying to convert an `std_logic_vector` to an `integer`. My code is this:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
use ieee.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.all;

entity shiftlogical is
  port(x     : in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
       shamt : in  std_logic_vector( 4 downto 0);
       y     : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0));
end shiftlogical;

architecture beh of shiftlogical is
  signal shift : integer;
  signal temp  : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
begin
  shift <= conv_integer(unsigned(shamt));
  temp  <= x(shift downto 0);
  y     <= temp;
end beh;
```

The code is not complete I know, but to test some ideas I am trying to pass `"00010"` (2) into `shamt`, but shift comes out to be -2147483648.  But I cannot figure out why it is doing this, nor can I find any resources online that shows anything different than what I am doing.  I greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: In my pending edit, I fixed a typo within the entity name (trailing space). I hope it is ok.

Comment: Didn't your simulator report an error in another line?

Answer (score 5):

-2147483648 (-2**31) is the default initial value for integers, being the leftmost, most negative value in its range. It suggests that the signal assignment to `shift` has not executed. Most likely because it is a continuous assignment and there hasn't been an event on `shamt` to cause it to update.

`std_logic_arith` is not an IEEE standard library. You should use `to_integer()` from `ieee.numeric_std` instead. It is also beneficial to keep numeric ports as `unsigned` or `signed` so that your intent is clear and to minimize type conversions. Also, you cannot directly assign the variable length slice of `x` to `temp` since their lengths do not match. You should use `resize()` (from numeric_std) to extend the length back to 32-bits or rethink your approach.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I changed some things around and used to_integer() instead to convert which seems to be working now.

Comment: @DavidDebreceni I can't believe this. Just replacing `conv_integer` by `to_integer` (and including `numeric_std`) does not solve your issue. `shift` is still -2**31 at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the obvious typo in the entity name, started the simulation (ModelSim) and forced the signal `shamt` to "00010". Then just after trying to run for 1 ps, ModelSim complains about:

> Fatal: (vsim-3420) Array lengths do not match. Left is 32 (31 downto 0). Right is 0 (-2147483648 downto 0 (null array)).
>
> Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Process: /shiftlogical/line__16 File: shiftlogical.vhdl
>
> Fatal error in Architecture beh at shiftlogical.vhdl line 16

That is because all your concurrent statements are executed in parallel. The new signal values are scheduled for the next delta cycle within the simulation. Thus, the line

```
  temp  <= x(shift downto 0);
```

is executed with the old value  of `shift` which is the initial value of this signal. The initial value of an integer is -2**31 as also Kevin pointed out.

Of course you can initialize the signal `shift`, but the only value which will not result in an error will be 31 because in this asignment the signal on the left and the expression on the right must match in array (`std_logic_vector`) size. The signal `shamt` must be forced to `"11111"` as well, so that `shift` keeps 31.

You cannot easily fix this, because for a left shift you must add zeros at the right (LSB) and for a right shift zeros or the sign at the left (MSB).

Answer (score 0):

@Martin Zabel what I had really tested there was to see if shift would hold an integer value which it did until I tried to pass it in for `temp <= x(shift downto 0);`  What I realized was that the signal needed to really be a variable to work as intended and as follows my code consists of:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
use ieee.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.all;

entity shiftlogical is
port(x: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
 shamt: in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
   dir: in std_logic;
     y: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0));
end shiftlogical;

architecture beh of shiftlogical is
begin
process(dir)
variable shift : integer;
begin
shift := conv_integer(unsigned(shamt));
if(dir = '0') then --Left shift
    y(31 downto shift) <= x(31-shift downto 0);
    y(shift downto 0) <= (others => '0');
elsif(dir = '1') then --Right shift
    y(31-shift downto 0) <= x(31 downto shift);
    y(31 downto 31-shift) <= (others => '0');
else --Always left shift
    y(31 downto shift) <= x(31-shift downto 0);
    y(shift downto 0) <= (others => '0');
end if;
end process;
end beh;
```

Comment: Yes, using a variable is another solution. And you see `conv_integer` works as expected, even it is not recommended. You should add `shamt`to the process sensitivity list, otherwise `y` will hold its value when only `shamt` but not `dir` changes it value. That is, you will get a latch or a difference between simulation and synthesis.